# On duplicate key ignore - Update multiple tables

Tags: mysql, insert, duplicates

I am attempting to insert data into two tables (table1 and table2), conditional on the uniqueness of the data being entered into table1. Table1 has a unique key set on pop & email & neighborhood. The idea is that if the same person submits the same pop in a neighborhood, then nothing happens in either table.  If someone else enters the same pop and neighborhood then it enters the data in table1 and increases the votes in table2 by 1.  I have heard some people talking about "on duplicate key ignore" which I think would work if implemented as below but I am not actually sure that the command is real:

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table1` VALUES ('$pop','$first', '$last', '$email',
'$neighborhood') on duplicate key ignore (INSERT INTO `table2` 
VALUES ('$pop', '$neighborhood','$votes', '$city') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
`votes` = `votes` +1)");
```

I have the following code working but understand that it will enter data into table2 
regardless of unique data in table1.

```
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table1` VALUtS ('$pop','$first', '$last', '$email', '$neighborhood')"); 
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `table2` VALUES ('$pop', '$neighborhood', '$votes', '$city') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `votes` = `votes` +1");
```

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Please stop using the deprecated `mysql_` functions. They are old and no longer maintained. Please switch to `mysqli` (`mysqli_`/`mysqli::`) or `PDO` (`PDO::`)

Comment: very interesting, I had no idea and will take a look at mysqli and pdo.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a single table? Change your unique key to pop,neighborhood,email (so pop,neighborhood are the leftmost two and can be used in a group by) and drop the 'votes' column. You can then run a query like `SELECT pop, neighborhood, count(*) AS votes FROM table1 GROUP BY pop,neighborhood;`

I don't think there's any such thing as `ON DUPLICATE KEY IGNORE`, but there is `INSERT IGNORE INTO ...` which basically says don't return any errors if the insert failed. If you need to keep separate tables you'll have to run the first query, check to see if you got a duplicate key error, then insert...on duplicate key update into the second table.

Comment: This seems reasonable.  My concern regarding one table was how long it would potentially take as the number of observations increased substantially.  It there is a summary table detailing the votes for each pop, neighborhood combination, couldn't it take a little while?

Comment: If you're planning on having hundreds of millions of votes with results being viewed several times per second and the results need to be 100% accurate, having the summary table would be a good idea. If there are <1m rows in the table, doing the group by on an index should return in under a second. If this is a high volume table and you do need the summary table, you'll have to run two queries.

Comment: Thanks Kadaan, that sounds good - I'll try and get that working.